# Programmatically turn off body summary

Tags: entities

My apologies if this is a duplicate, but I spent two days using my Google-foo to find this information and never did. So, now that I've figured it out, I'll post it here.

## The Question

**How do I turn off the body summary programmatically?**

Answer (score 0):

I placed this code directly after my call to `node_add_body_field('my_node_type')`.

```
  $field_instance = field_info_instance('node', 'body', 'my_node_type');
  $field_instance['settings']['display_summary'] = FALSE;
  field_update_instance($field_instance);
```

### References

- [`node_add_body_field()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_add_body_field/7)
- [`field_info_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7)
- [`field_update_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_instance/7)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do so is to use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'my_content_type_node_form')  {
    $form['body'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['summary']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: while that is an effective way to hide the summary, my specific objective was to toggle off the **Summary input** option for the body field, much as you would by manually editing the field and unchecking the **Summary input** checkbox.

To put it another way: I don't just want to hide the summary; I wanted it turned off at the field instance level.

Comment: So you mean the checkbox in the field settings?! I don't see any reference on that in your question. Either way I guess hook_form_alter can do the job.